# Батник, запуск программы, разное количество раз с разными параметрами

Tags: bat

Есть программа, она на вход принимает XMl c конфигом и в зависимости от содержимого конфига выполняет задачи. 
Вопрос в том что порой их надо запускать достаточно много, но часто какое то фиксированное количество.

Для одиночного запуска используется такая конструкция:

```
for %%i in (.\conf.*.xml) do ^
start "%%i" cmd /C java -jar prog.jar %%i
```

Для двух раз получил следующее:

```
for/l %%i in (1,1,2) do start "%%i" cmd /C java -jar prog.jar .\conf.*.xml
```

Но данный вариант не работает если есть несколько вариантов отвечающих условию `.\conf.*.xml`, плюс заголовок становится не имя XML, а 1 и 2, что не приемлемо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /L %%j in (1,1,2) do (
    for %%i in (.\conf.*.xml) do (
        start "pass %%j: %%i" cmd /C java -jar prog.jar %%i
    )
)
```